# How do we standardize data for higher moments?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I know that if I want to transform some data points to a mean of zero and standard deviation to 1 I can use this formula:

$$Z= \frac{x-μ}{σ}$$

However if for example I want for example to normalize my data in such a way so that:

$$E[X^3]=a$$
I am not aware or was able to find or come up with a formula/transform that can do such a thing

Also, how do I generalize this to higher moments transform?
$$E[X^n]=a_n$$
Any formulas, derivations and explanations are highly appreciated!

Comment: You could first calculate $E[X^3]$ and then multiply $X$ by $\sqrt[3]{a/E[X^3]}$.

Comment: @KurtG. Can such a thing work for higher moments too?

Comment: Using $\sqrt[n]{a_n/E[X^n]}$ perhaps ?

Comment: @KurtG. That wasn't exactly what I had on my mind. What I want is a  one to one transform so my points can have whatever moments I want them to

Comment: Please be more specific. With that last formula your "points" will have the $n$-th moment $a_n$ which you can choose. What else you want exactly ?

Comment: @KurtG. Let's say for example we have a bunch of points (or samples if the naming is confusing) X={1, 3, 5, 12, 5}. If I would want to normalize this so it has a mean of zero and a σ of one, then I would need to subtract the mean and remove σ. My question is how to generalize this behaviour for higher moments

Comment: Choose the CDF that has your favourite moments. Call it $F(x)$. Let $G(x)$ be the CDF of $X$. Then $Y=F^{-1}(G(X))$ has CDF $F$, hence the desired moments. Is that what you want ?

Comment: @KurtG. Yes! thank you